# Flutter Navigation routes not run smoothly

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using  `Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/RegisterScreen');` to Navigate to Register Screen but it not run smoothly , It seems that the first screen under the second one for about half a second on navigation

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

push or pushNamed doesn't close current screen if you want to new screen get replace(not on) your current screen you need to use pushReplacement or pushReplacementNamed method

so try below code and check [methods in flutter documents](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html#static-methods) to get the whole idea about navigation:

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/RegisterScreen');
```

Comment: yes I know what do you mean , but in my issue that am facing some lagging in the animation of routing between login screen to register screen  so login screen not quick disappear it still appear under the register screen for a while

Comment: That could happen beacuse of works in your screens or some asstes has big size, heavy work can cause lag but if you think bypass this animation you can use initialRoute. And I highly recommend to try your app with a real device if you are using an emulator because emulator performance is never great and cause lags usually.

Answer (score -2):

I was experiencing this lag as well, running debug mode on chrome. Despite not having any lag on debug mode in a emulator.

Running chrome on profile mode, as @Lunedor suggested,  seems to eliminate all these performance issues.

Comment: Can you add more details like which library you was using for Navigation in flutter  , GoRouter, AutoRoute or other.